# How Can I add Extra Product Meta in the Woocommerce Product Listing?

Tags: woocommerce

[image: I want to add product meta like this]

I want to add product meta in my [Online Cosmetics Store](https://amarpriyo.com) like the above screenshot.

This meta data is exists in an opencart website shop4shops.in. I want to add the same meta data in my Woocommerce store.

Your help, will be appreciated.

Comment: this question is not really detailed and clear… Is this meta data exist somewhere? How is this data set in the product? … please update your question and add all necessary details, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this meta data is exists in an opencart website shop4shops.in. I want to add the same meta data in my Woocommerce store.

Comment: In backend, you can use product attributes, or better custom fields maid with code (like in the answer below) or more easily with for example Advanced Custom fields plugin… In front end you might need some custom code… Here is one of the examples that you will find in StackOverFlow, that you will have to customize for your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805305/display-product-post-type-advanced-custom-field-on-recent-orders-template-and-ad/37895142#37895142

Answer (score 0):

i will give you small demo for how to add meta for product.

in function.php file add following code.

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'pharmacy_meta_boxes' );

  function pharmacy_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
      $meta_boxes[] = array(
      'title'  => __( 'Extra Product Info', 'pharmacy' ),
      'fields' => array(
                        array(
                               'id' => 'unit',
                               'name' => __( 'Unit', 'pharmacy' ),
                               'type' => 'text',
                               'datalist' => array(
                                             'options' => array(
                                              __( 'Box', 'pharmacy' ),
                                              __( 'Blister pack', 'pharmacy' ),
                                              __( 'Packet', 'pharmacy' ),
                                              __( 'Bottle', 'pharmacy' ),
                                             ),
                             ), 
                        ),
                        array(
                               'id'   => 'dosage_form',
                               'name' => __( 'Dosage form', 'pharmacy' ),
                               'type' => 'text',
                               'datalist' => array(
                                             'options' => array(
                                             __( 'Capsule', 'pharmacy' ),
                                             __( 'Tablet', 'pharmacy' ),
                                             __( 'Liquid', 'pharmacy' ),
                                             __( 'Ointment', 'pharmacy' ),
                               ),
                            ),
                        ),
                   );

       return $meta_boxes;
 }
```

And to save that meta write following in your function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'pharmacy_extra_info' );
  function pharmacy_extra_info()
     {
      if ( $meta = rwmb_meta( 'unit' ) )
        {
          echo '<strong>' . __( 'Unit:', 'pharmacy' ) . "</strong> $meta<br>";
        }
       if ( $meta = rwmb_meta( 'dosage_form' ) )
        {
           echo '<strong>' . __( 'Dosage form:', 'pharmacy' ) . "</strong> $meta<br>";
       }
 }
```

I hope this following code help you to add meta in your product and you can add more product meta like this way.

and you can also follow 
[this link](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-product-information-in-woocommerce/)

Thank You.