# Set product custom field and display value in cart, checkout and view order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I've created a custom field for warranty in my products pages, via function.php.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'test_custom_fields' );
function test_custom_fields() {
    // Print a custom text field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => '_warranty',
        'label' => 'i.e. 15 years',
        'description' => '',
        'desc_tip' => 'true',
        'placeholder' => 'i.e. 15 years'
    ) );        
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'test_save_custom_fields' );
function test_save_custom_fields( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['_warranty'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_warranty', esc_attr( $_POST['_warranty'] ) );
    }
}
```

I would like to "duplicate" this custom field with key and value, in an self-generated custom field on the admin order page depending on products in cart/order (without plugin).

So, with this custom field on order page, I will finally be able to display "warranty" in my pdf invoice with WooCommerce PDF Invoice plugin.

Another explanation :

1. As admin, I fill _warranty value in "product1" page
2. When "product1" is in an order, on the admin order view, I would like to see a custom field containing "_warranty + value" from product1 page.
3. So, as admin, I could set **`{{_warranty}}`** in WooCommerce PDF Invoice plugin to display "Warranty : 15 years"

Many thanks for your help.

I have just tested the following case: [show product meta in order items table in Order Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644420/show-product-meta-in-order-items-table-in-order-details/25645735#25645735)

But this does not give me a custom field, so I couldn't get my **`{{_warranty}}`** value width it.

What I am doing wrong? 
How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like [Product Add Ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/) might be a good fit for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **First:** *"Duplicating this custom field with key and value, in an self-generated custom field on the admin order page"* **is not the good approach.**

To achieve what you are expecting, you have missed just some little things. You need to:

1. Store custom field in Cart (when product is added to cart)
2. Render this on cart and checkout pages
3. Add the information in the order as meta data (to make it part of the order)

> With **point 3** you will be able to get this on WooCommerce PDF Invoice plugin to display "Warranty : 15 years".

So the code you need is:

```
// create the custom field on product admin tab
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'create_warranty_custom_field' );
function create_warranty_custom_field() {
    // Create a custom text field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_warranty',
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Warranty', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'   => '',
        'desc_tip'      => 'true',
        'placeholder'   =>  __('i.e. 15 years', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
}

// save the data value from this custom field on product admin tab
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_warranty_custom_field' );
function save_warranty_custom_field( $post_id ) {
    $wc_text_field = $_POST['_warranty'];
    if ( !empty($wc_text_field) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_warranty', esc_attr( $wc_text_field ) );
    }
}

// Store custom field in Cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'store_warranty_custom_field', 10, 2 );

function store_warranty_custom_field( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    $warranty_item = get_post_meta( $product_id , '_warranty', true );
    if( !empty($warranty_item) ) {
        $cart_item_data[ '_warranty' ] = $warranty_item;

        // below statement make sure every add to cart action as unique line item
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
        WC()->session->set( 'days_manufacture', $warranty_item );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}


// Render meta on cart and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'rendering_meta_field_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );

function rendering_meta_field_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $custom_items = array();
    // Woo 2.4.2 updates
    if( !empty( $cart_data ) ) {
        $custom_items = $cart_data;
    }
    if( isset( $cart_item['_warranty'] ) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array( "name" => __( "Warranty", "woocommerce" ), "value" => $cart_item['_warranty'] );
    }
    return $custom_items;
}

// Add the information in the order as meta data
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','add_waranty_to_order_item_meta', 1, 3 );
function add_waranty_to_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Retrieving the product id for the order $item_id
    $product_id = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_product_id', true );
    // Getting the warranty value for this product Id
    $warranty = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_warranty', true );
    // Add the meta data to the order
    wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'Warranty', $warranty, true);
}
```

*Naturally, this goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**This code is tested and works.**

---

References:

- [WooCommerce : Add custom Metabox to admin order page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772912/woocommerce-add-custom-metabox-to-admin-order-page)
- [Admin product pages custom field displayed in Cart and checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237450/admin-product-pages-custom-field-displayed-in-cart-and-checkout/39239846#39239846)

Comment: I've just tested your code and unfortunately I get a 502 Bad Gatweay when I apply it in my function.php.
Do you have any idea ?
And if possible, I do not want to add this field in my cart and checkout pages, this information "warranty" is not necessary on this pages. It's only necessary in my invoices. Could you also please remove the unnecessary code from 
I'm not a developer, so very noob in php ...
many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

There is an error at the end of the code, you call a variable `$prod_id` at first, and then `$product_id`. Correct and working code is:

```
// Add the information in the order as meta data
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','add_waranty_to_order_item_meta', 1, 3 );
function add_waranty_to_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Retrieving the product id for the order $item_id
    $prod_id = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_product_id', true );
    // Getting the warranty value for this product Id
    $warranty = get_post_meta( $prod_id, '_warranty', true );
    // Add the meta data to the order
    wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'Warranty', $warranty, true);
}
```