# is it possible after customer place a order and then admin assign a specific order to a vendor in wc marketplace plugin

Tags: woocommerce

> Is it possible after customer place a order and then admin assign a
>   specific order to a vendor in **wc marketplace plugin**

Answer (score 1):

WCMarketplace keeps vendor orders as dc_commission - post type.
I have researched when you creating order with vendor product. WCmarketplace creates **dc_commision** post 
in the database, you could see all this post with such SQL query
`SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_type = 'dc_commission'`

Then, also, wcmarketplace creates meta keys for this field.
You could use such SQL query for seeing this
`SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta where post_id = 14;`

The meta keys are

**_commission_vendor**
**_commission_product**
**_shipping**
**_tax**
**_commission_order_id**
**_paid_status**
**_commission_amount**

There is no standard functionality for your purpose.

You could add this functionality by this steps

1. You could create a custom meta box for admin order page.
   [WooCommerce : Add custom Metabox to admin order page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772912/woocommerce-add-custom-metabox-to-admin-order-page)
2. You could write code for metabox. For creating new post with post type 'dc_commision' and then add post meta **_commission_vendor**
   **_commission_product**
   **_shipping**
   **_tax**
   **_commission_order_id**
   **_paid_status**
   **_commission_amount**

Where commission_order_id = is current page order id. Other parameters you could write by researching then in other **dc_commisions** post type analogically.
3. You could add functionality to your meta box for choosing a vendor and set **_commission_vendor** id. This id is in wp_users_meta table with meta key *vendor_term_id*. You could get vendor_term_id and then set to **_commission_vendor**.